# CSE check qouta count

Tags: php, rest, api, google-custom-search

Google custom search API gives a limit of 100 requests per day.

On what route can I check how many requests have been made today using REST api?

I can see the same data by links in CONSOLE, but not in the JSON result
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/customsearch.googleapis.com/quotas?project=XXX
https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?project=XXX